# The `lookup_friendships` function from `rtweet` package: matrix storage

Tags: r, api, rtweet

The `lookup_friendships` function from `rtweet` package, gives information on friendship between two Twitter users. For example:

```
x<-lookup_friendships("user1","user0")
x<-x %>% filter(relationship=="source", variable == "following")
value<-x$value
```

`value` is `TRUE` if `user1` is a follower of `user0` and `FALSE` otherwise. In my problem I have a list of users, e.g. `user0`, `user1`, `user2` and so on. I would like to store the results of previous code,

```
x<-lookup_friendships("useri","userj")
x<-x %>% filter(relationship=="source", variable == "following")
value<-x$value
```

for each `i>j` in a matrix. How culd I proceed

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `df` is your dataframe with colmns `user.source`, `user.target`.

```
df$is.follower <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
 df$user.source[i] -> source
 df$user.target[i] -> target
 lookup_friendship(source, target) %>% 
  filter(relationship == "source", variable == "following") %>%
  select(value) -> output
  if(output == TRUE){
   df$is.follower[i] <- TRUE
  } else {
   df$is.follower[i] <- FALSE
}
```